# How to send push options with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: libgit2sharp

How to use LibGit2Sharp to send parameters to server similar to the command `git --push-option`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

See [PushOptions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/PushOptions.cs)

```
PushOptions options = new PushOptions()
{
    CredentialsProvider = new LibGit2Sharp.Handlers.CredentialsHandler((url, usernameFromUrl, types) => credentials),
};

repo.Network.Push(CurrentBranch, options);
```

Thanks,

Garrick

Comment: Thanks Garrick, but that not answer the question, because what you showed us it's just the authentication part in the conection with the server, but does not send any parameters to the pre-receive hook as the manual [git --push-option=<option>](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---push-optionltoptiongt) says.